# File system for intermediary data storage between Linux and Windows

Tags: windows, filesystem, accessibility

What is the best file system for intermediary data storage between Linux and Windows that requires no or the least overhead cost of remap, mount etc?

Answer (score 2):

Currently NTFS is the best choice (supported and it doesn't have the limitations of FAT). But you have to disable fast boot on Windows 10 so it won't send the partition to a half-hibernated state on shutdown. After doing this, you can also mount it permanently on Linux without problems.